# Flutter Geolocator and Google Maps: Show static location

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-maps, geolocation

I am having trouble with the following implementation:

My Flutter app is working fine when the user gives location permissions but when the user denies the permissions I am in trouble. The shows a Loading Indicator when loading the Google Map but when the user denies the permissions it keeps spinning. I want to implement a error message that shows that the permission is needed but I don't know how.

Below the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:hvd_test/styling/colors.dart';
import 'package:hvd_test/models/navigation.dart';
import 'package:hvd_test/models/markers.dart';

// This page shows a Google Map plugin with all stations (HvD and Total). The markers are pulled from a Firebase database.

class StationsMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StationsMap createState() => _StationsMap();
}

class _StationsMap extends State<StationsMap> {
  
  bool mapToggle = false;

  var currentLocation;

  GoogleMapController mapController;

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

// Below function initiates all HvD stations and shows them as markers on the map. It also generates a Bottom Sheet for each location with corresponding information. 

  void initMarkerHvD(specify, specifyId) async {
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final Uint8List markerHvD = await getBytesFromAsset('images/Pin-HvD.JPG', 70);
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Color(0xff757575),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0)
                          )
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              specify['stationName'], style: TextStyle(color: PaletteBlue.hvdblue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16), textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(
                              specify['stationAddress']
                            ),
                            Text(
                              specify['stationZIP'] + ' ' + specify['stationCity']
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Navigeer naar locatie',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        PaletteOrange.hvdorange)),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  MapUtils.openMap(
                                      specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
                                      specify['stationLocation'].longitude);
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
      },
      position: LatLng(specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
          specify['stationLocation'].longitude),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerHvD),
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

// Below function initiates all Total stations and shows them as markers on the map. It also generates a Bottom Sheet for each location with corresponding information. 

  void initMarkerTotal(specify, specifyId) async {
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final Uint8List markerTotal = await getBytesFromAsset('images/Pin-Total.JPG', 70);
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Color(0xff757575),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0)
                          )
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              specify['stationName'], style: TextStyle(color: PaletteBlue.hvdblue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16), textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(
                              specify['stationAddress']
                            ),
                            Text(
                              specify['stationZIP'] + ' ' + specify['stationCity']
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Navigeer naar locatie',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        PaletteOrange.hvdorange)),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  MapUtils.openMap(
                                      specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
                                      specify['stationLocation'].longitude);
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
      },
      position: LatLng(specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
          specify['stationLocation'].longitude),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerTotal),
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

// Below functions pulls all HvD markers from the database. 

  getMarkerDataHvD() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('hvd-stations')
        .get()
        .then((myMarkers) {
      if (myMarkers.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myMarkers.docs.length; i++) {
          initMarkerHvD(myMarkers.docs[i].data(), myMarkers.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

// Below function pulls all Total markers from the database. 

  getMarkerDataTotal() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('total-stations')
        .get()
        .then((myMarkers) {
      if (myMarkers.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myMarkers.docs.length; i++) {
          initMarkerTotal(myMarkers.docs[i].data(), myMarkers.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

// Below function initiates all previous functions on the page. This happens when the user navigates to the page. 

  void initState() {
    getMarkerDataHvD();
    getMarkerDataTotal();
    super.initState();
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,)
        .then((currloc) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = currloc;
        mapToggle = true;
      });
    });
  }

// Below function is used to display all previous functions to the page. 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            mapToggle
                ? GoogleMap(
                    onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
                    markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                    gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
                      new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                        () => new EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                      ),
                    ].toSet(),
                    mapToolbarEnabled: false,
                    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                    scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(
                          currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
                      zoom: 12.0,
                    ),
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: PaletteOrange.hvdorange,
                    ),
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onMapCreated(controller) {
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
    });
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE 04-08-2021:**

So I changed the code to always show the map on a static point. When the user don't gives permission they can use the map without location.

But when the user gives permission for the location the map would automatically move to the position on the map...

I now have the problem that when the user gives permission the camera does not move to the users location, it works when I give permission and then use the MyLocation Button but I would like it to be automatic... It is driving me nuts!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:hvd_test/styling/colors.dart';
import 'package:hvd_test/models/navigation.dart';
import 'package:hvd_test/models/markers.dart';

// This page shows a Google Map plugin with all stations (HvD and Total). The markers are pulled from a Firebase database.

class StationsMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StationsMap createState() => _StationsMap();
}

class _StationsMap extends State<StationsMap> {

  bool _isLocationGranted = false;

  var currentLocation;

  GoogleMapController mapController;

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

// Below function initiates all HvD stations and shows them as markers on the map. It also generates a Bottom Sheet for each location with corresponding information. 

  void initMarkerHvD(specify, specifyId) async {
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final Uint8List markerHvD = await getBytesFromAsset('images/Pin-HvD.JPG', 70);
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Color(0xff757575),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0)
                          )
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              specify['stationName'], style: TextStyle(color: PaletteBlue.hvdblue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16), textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(
                              specify['stationAddress']
                            ),
                            Text(
                              specify['stationZIP'] + ' ' + specify['stationCity']
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Navigeer naar locatie',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        PaletteOrange.hvdorange)),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  MapUtils.openMap(
                                      specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
                                      specify['stationLocation'].longitude);
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
      },
      position: LatLng(specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
          specify['stationLocation'].longitude),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerHvD),
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

// Below function initiates all Total stations and shows them as markers on the map. It also generates a Bottom Sheet for each location with corresponding information. 

  void initMarkerTotal(specify, specifyId) async {
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final Uint8List markerTotal = await getBytesFromAsset('images/Pin-Total.JPG', 70);
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Color(0xff757575),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0)
                          )
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              specify['stationName'], style: TextStyle(color: PaletteBlue.hvdblue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16), textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(
                              specify['stationAddress']
                            ),
                            Text(
                              specify['stationZIP'] + ' ' + specify['stationCity']
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Navigeer naar locatie',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        PaletteOrange.hvdorange)),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  MapUtils.openMap(
                                      specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
                                      specify['stationLocation'].longitude);
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
      },
      position: LatLng(specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
          specify['stationLocation'].longitude),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerTotal),
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

// Below functions pulls all HvD markers from the database. 

  getMarkerDataHvD() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('hvd-stations')
        .get()
        .then((myMarkers) {
      if (myMarkers.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myMarkers.docs.length; i++) {
          initMarkerHvD(myMarkers.docs[i].data(), myMarkers.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

// Below function pulls all Total markers from the database. 

  getMarkerDataTotal() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('total-stations')
        .get()
        .then((myMarkers) {
      if (myMarkers.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myMarkers.docs.length; i++) {
          initMarkerTotal(myMarkers.docs[i].data(), myMarkers.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

// Below function initiates all previous functions on the page. This happens when the user navigates to the page. 

  void initState() {
    getMarkerDataHvD();
    getMarkerDataTotal();
    super.initState();
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
        .then((currloc) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = currloc;
        _isLocationGranted = true;
      });
    });
  }

// Below function is used to display all previous functions to the page. 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
                    onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
                    markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                    gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
                      new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                        () => new EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                      ),
                    ].toSet(),
                    mapToolbarEnabled: false,
                    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                    scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
                    myLocationEnabled: _isLocationGranted,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(51.8876176, 5.4278765),
                      zoom: 12.0,
                    ),
                  )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onMapCreated(controller) {
      mapController = controller;
      mapController.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(currentLocation));
  }
}
```

Comment: In geolocator package you have option to check if the user accepts the permission and if the user enable the location service or not.check under usage there will be example how to use it

Comment: I am new to Flutter and I did check the documentation and have seen the function but I don't know how to implement it in the code above.

Comment: Also refer this code,it was used one of my projects https://stackoverflow.com/a/64403196/13418165@EnricovanDijkhuizen

Answer (score 0):

Ok, You can use this package `permission_handler` to check if the user denies the permission or accept it. Easy to use package.

**NOTE :** don't forgot to add the permissions you will deal with it in the `Podfile` file. if you do not add this edit to `podfile` you will face an issue with permission when you try to upload to AppStore. You should read the documentation.

Package link : https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: See the comment I placed above. In the Geolocator package there is already a function to check for permissions but I don't know how to implement it to my code shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code,i didn't  test,try this and let me know

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

/// Determine the current position of the device.
///
/// When the location services are not enabled or permissions
/// are denied the `Future` will return an error.
Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  // Test if location services are enabled.
  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled don't continue
    // accessing the position and request users of the 
    // App to enable the location services.
//instead this add a snackbar 
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale 
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
//instead this add a snackbar 
      return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }
  
  if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately. 
//instead this add a snackbar 
    return Future.error(
      'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
  } 

  // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
  // continue accessing the position of the device.
  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,)
        .then((currloc) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = currloc;
        mapToggle = true;
      print("LAT: ${currentLocation .latitude}, LNG: ${currentLocation .longitude}");
      });
    });
}
```

Call the above method in initState

```
void initState() {
    getMarkerDataHvD();
    getMarkerDataTotal();
    super.initState();
    _determinePosition();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I already tried this but when I implement this it is not working. I keep the CircularProgressIndicator and don't get a error message in the app. I think it has something to do with the implementation of mapToggle and CircularProgressIndicator but I don't know how to adjust it.

Comment: can you try this mapToggle!=true
                ? GoogleMap():Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: PaletteOrange.hvdorange,
                    ),
                  ), @EnricovanDijkhuizen

Comment: Again thank you for your help. When I do this I get the following error message:

The getter 'latitude' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: latitude
The relevant error-causing widget was
StationsMap
lib\pages\stations.dart:46

Comment: it's look like lattitude is null,I have updated the code,try run again there is print with lat and long,tell me the output@EnricovanDijkhuizen

Comment: I ran your code and get this back:

`
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The getter 'latitude' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: latitude
The relevant error-causing widget was
StationsMap
lib\pages\stations.dart:46
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5739): LAT: 51.8876167, LNG: 5.427875
`

Comment: what are you using  lib\pages\stations.dart@EnricovanDijkhuizen

Comment: That's the page that holds the 3 tabs. stationsMap, stationsHvD, stationsTotal so it is the page that gets called from the Menu.

Comment: I think the problem is at calling lattitude and longtidude data from the firestore make sure you returns all data,print out the response of firestore data,i am not familiar with firestore also try remove `markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),` from google map widget,if it shows current location then it mostly about not parsing correctly from firbase or no data in firestore @EnricovanDijkhuizen