# Flutter - Get Current User Location

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, geolocation

I saw that there are several methods to obtain the current user's location on flutter. I shortlisted it to two but cannot find which one would be more suitable and why. These are the flutter geolocator package and Google API.

Does someone have any experience using those? Which one would you recommend?

The app I am building needs high accuracy. I made a test and saw there is a little difference between the results obtained from the two. However, I have no idea which one is the most accurate.

Example:

Geolocator: Latitude = xx.xxx3127

Google API: Latitude =xx.xxx322

Answer (score 0):

Geolocator is a good option to use for finding location

You can see the code in the attached link to find out how you can use it.

[Flutter Geolocator and Google Maps: Show static location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68632810/flutter-geolocator-and-google-maps-show-static-location)

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I managed to implement both solutions. I'm just not sure which one would be considered the best between Geolocator and Google API